# Reshaping a vector into a bigger matrix with complicated fill rules in R

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, data-structures, reshape

I have a vector `Z` of length K < N*S which contains all non-zero values. I want to create a new matrix `Y` with dimensions N x S from the vector `Z`.

I have another vector `n.positive` which is length S. `n.positive[s]` tells me how many values in `Z` to insert into row s of matrix `Y` (the rest of the entries are zero). Consequently, `sum(n.positive)` equals K.

I would like to do this in R.

For example,

```
y <- matrix(rep(0, N*S), nrow=S)
n.pos <- rbinom(S, N, theta)
Z <- rnorm(sum(n.pos))
```

Comment: It would have been better with an example.  Perhaps `Y[cbind(seq_len(N), n.pos)] <- Z`

Comment: What kind of info would you like in an example that's not in the question? I've given you the vector I'd like to reshape and the vector that gives me some rules for reshaping. Not much else to it.

Comment: what i meant is a small example that mimics the issue so that others can test your condition.  The reason is that people may not spend time to create some example thinking that it may or may not be the actual issue.   I hope you understand it.

Answer (score -1):

```
row.idx <- unlist(lapply(1:length(n.pos), function(x) rep(x, n.pos[x])))
col.idx <- unlist(lapply(n.pos, function(x) seq_len(x)))
y[row.idx + nrow(y) * (col.idx - 1)] <- Z
```